Tricky error using conda with "Bad CPU type in executable" on new M3 Chip
I'm having some difficulty understanding what is causing my "Bad CPU type in executable" error when using conda.  This error occurs on several of my terminal commands, but I'll illustrate it below on "conda":
$ brew install anaconda 
....(works successfully, and installs in PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/anaconda3) 
$ conda 
__conda_exe:1: no such file or directory: /usr/local/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/bin/conda 
$. /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda  
(...as expected, returns usage info)
$ /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda create -n new_env python=3.12 anaconda 
returns "Bad CPU executable" 

You can see that when I give it the explicit path to conda (/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda), it seems to recognize it, but then causes errors downstream when I try to run specific commands.
I've seen the answers  zsh: bad CPU type in executable: ngrok and zsh: bad CPU type in executable .  However, the answers aren't consistent, and none of them seem to address changes that might have been introduced by the new M3 chip.
EDIT/UPDATE:
I got a little bit closer by doing the following:

export PATH='/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH'
conda init zsh
restarting my zsh shell

After doing those things, then at least the shell recognizes the commands brew and conda.  However, when I try again to use conda to create a new virtual environment:

I use "conda create -n new_env python=3.12 anaconda"
And at first it appears to be working fine, until I see the following:

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(945): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::python.app-3-py312h80987f9_0'.                                              
Rolling back transaction: done                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                       
[Errno 86] Bad CPU type in executable: '/usr/local/bin/bash'                                                                                                           
()                                                                       

There must be a system-wide issue going on here.  What can I do about this?

This is usually some Intel code that hasn't been recompiled for AS.

Thanks @benwiggy.  Is there an easy way to fix that?

Run anaconda entirely in Rosetta. (assuming that everything is a Universal Binary with AS and Intel forks.)

Thanks.  I got a little closer (see the EDIT/UPDATE:).  How do I check if "everything is a Universal Binary with AS and Intel forks"?

This is expected behavior - have you decided if you want to run in Rosetta or reinstall everything for the new architecture? If the former, these steps are needed to validate your plan.

Thanks @bmike.  I'm fine with either (I think?).  Is there any reason to reinstall everything for the new architecture?  My hesitation is that these aren't apps per se - they're simple terminal commands which I would expect to be easy to re-install.

Furthermore, did I mess anything up that might prevent rosetta from running successfully, when I tried to do some of the installation manually as shown in my question with the EDIT/UPDATE?

I would run things with Rosetta until you have a performance issue or the arch setting becomes too cumbersome to have stick. I could see using the arch -x86_64 zsh trick short term, but want to get things sorted and cleanly installed in the longer term.

I agree that the arch trick from the question you linked to is quite cumbersome (and I'll probably forget it sometimes).  When you say "getting things sorted and cleanly installed", you mean what specifically?  Is there any harm in just adding arch -arm64 zsh to my .zprofile script and proceeding as normal?

How did you install /usr/local/bin/bash ? I suspect that you need to install bash via homebrew and delete that one.
